# What is the usability of isize and usize, and why are they beneficial to indexing?

Tags: types, rust

I am learning Rust and reading through docs, when i stumbled upon `isize` and `usize` data types. There was following mention in the docs:

> The primary situation in which you’d use isize or usize is when
> indexing some sort of collection.

Collections are data types like vector or tuple. However I cannot see why `isize` and `usize` are beneficial to use when it comes to indexing. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Because they're sized appropriately to the memory architecture being compiled for. If on a 32bit memory architecture, you get a 32bit datatype, if on a 64bit memory architecture, you get a 64bit datatype.  If you're using integers to represent positions in memory (relative Or absolute) having the smallest datatype that's guaranteed to be big enough is surely a good thing?

Comment: note that isize don't make much sense, the name is more here to be symetric to usize but it's more an offset that a size

Comment: `usize` an `usize` are pointer-sized, which means `usize` can represent an index into a sequence (memory can be through of as a sequence of bytes so a pointer is an index in there) and `isize` can represent the difference of two indices. Incidentally a tuple is not a collection (in Rust, and in general, some languages like Python treat tuples as collections but that's the exception rather than the rule), a tuple is really an anonymous structure, although their fields are defined positionally they're not indexable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isize and usize are beneficial to indexing because isize is the pointer-sized signed integer type and usize is the pointer-sized unsigned integer type.

Remember that isize can be negative, but usize cannot be negative.

And although it is true that isize and usize are the same size right now, later on it might not be due to the machine architecture.

Comment: What is a pointer-sized integer? What do you mean by "pointer-sized"? Do you mean it has the same size as a pointer? But why is this concept even useful for or related to indexing data structures?

Comment: For anyone wondering, it's because arr[i] means "take the starting address of arr (which is a pointer), add i to it, then get the thing at that address". In order to do the "add" part, then the index i needs to have the same size/signedness as a pointer, in order to be added to the starting pointer. That or it needs to be converted beforehand, implicitly in many other languages, explicitly in Rust.